# Do professional killstreak effects show up on hats?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Due to a recent bug in the Gun Mettle update (which has since been patched), Specialized Killstreak and Professional Killstreak kits/fabricators can be found in MvM and applied to any item (including hats).

Since this patch, the only way to obtain such items is via the [Steam community market](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Professional%20Killstreak%20Kit%20Fabricator), and they're very expensive.

I'm considering buying one, but I need to know beforehand: do the Professional Killstreak effects apply to the hats? e.g. If I have killed 10 people with a Killstreak shotgun and am wearing a Professional killstreak Gibus, will the Professional Killstreaker show (even though I have no Professional Killstreak **weapons**)?

Answer (score 1):

From the wiki:

> When a Killstreak weapon is equipped, a kill counter appears in the player's HUD, tracking the number of kills made with any Killstreak weapon equipped.

Killstreak items work by counting the kills made by the weapon in a single life - for the counter to be incremented, it must be the weapon that kills a player.

Since you cannot kill players with hats, and assists do not count to a killstreak (removing the possibility of a hat (e.g. alienswarm parasite) counting kills), any killstreak hats will be useless other than their title, and to gain any killstreak effect (including those of the hat) you will need to already have a killstreak weapon logging your kills.

**A killstreak hat will not give a sheen, but WILL give other killstreak-unique effects.**

Comment: Exactly. But this doesn't answer the question. Killstreak weapons count the number of kills made by **any** killstreak weapon in a single life. I could kill someone 10 times with a killstreak shotgun in a single life, switch to a professional killstreak powerjack, and the powerjack's killstreaker effect would show, even though I haven't killed anyone with the powerjack in that life. I'm asking if the same applies to professional killstreak hats.

Comment: I've edited my post for clarity concerning the point I was trying to make.